# Can std::call_once be reset?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-call-once

I wrote a function a while ago, based on [Unreal Engine 4's blueprint implementation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/Blueprints/UserGuide/FlowControl/index.html#doonce), that invokes a callable exactly once until it is reset:

```cpp
template<typename Callable>
void DoOnce(Callable&& f, bool reset = false, bool start_closed = false) noexcept {
    static bool once = start_closed;
    if(!once) {
        once = true;
        std::invoke(f);
    }
    if(reset) {
        once = false;
    }
}
```

Today I learned [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) exists, works across threads, works with callables that have arguments, tests for exception-safety, and basically wraps around `std::invoke` like mine does (the MSVC implementation at least).

That sounds great and, where possible, I prefer calling a pre-existing function over writing my own anyway.

Like Unreal's documentaion suggests, there are times that I may need to invoke the callable again by resetting the internal flag; **can `std::call_once` be reset in order to allow the underlying callable to be invoked again?**

Comment: well, you can reset the flag by making a new one with placement-new . I don't see anything in the standard that would rule that out, although it smells a bit fishy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard isn't kidding when they call it "once_flag". It's a flag that only gets set once.

You can of course call the function multiple times, with *different* once-flag objects. But to do this properly, you need to hand each thread that might attempt to call it the new once-flag object. It can't just be a global or static object somewhere; you have to actually marshal each new invocation out to all of the threads that want to call it.

Comment: @Casey: Well, you're the one who's trying to `call_once` a thing *more than once*. Grossness is kind of expected ;)

Comment: Call once looks like "magic statics, but without the statics" exposed by the standard to me.  Like, `static const bool unused=(static_cast<void>(f()),true);` without the noise.

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer, but on the understanding that it's a long-winded way to say: "No, that's not what it's used for." :) Using the STL or standard improperly is inviting disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is hack for that. You could have something like:

```
using namespace std;

auto flag = make_unique<once_flag>();

void f(int x) {
    cout << x << " f called\n";
}

int main()
{
    call_once(*flag, f, 5);
    call_once(*flag, f, 15); // This one won't be called
    flag = make_unique<once_flag>(); // "resets" the flag
    call_once(*flag, f, 15); // This one will be called
    return 0;
}
```